# How can I set the zone like I want?

Tags: simcity-4

Suppose that I have 2 roads like those below and I want to zone ONE residential with an entrance (^) on east/west road ( the house is on a field of 3 squares)

`+++...++++++++`
`..............`
`..............`
`+++...++++++++`
`^ +...+`
`^ +...+`
`^ +...+`

But the computer does not let me build the way I want. It set 3 residential zones of one sqare each on north/south road instead.

`+++...++++++++`
`..............`
`..............`
`+++...++++++++`
`> +...+`
`> +...+`
`> +...+`

How can I set the zone the way I want ?
Am not suppose to act like god ?  :-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When zoning you can hold the following keys (or any combination) to adjust how it will configure the plots:

- <kbd>**Shift**</kbd>:   Temporarily disables automatic street placement
- <kbd>**Alt**</kbd>:   Rotates zone to face perpendicular road
- <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd>:   Forces a specific plot size

It sounds like you would want to use the <kbd>**Alt**</kbd> key.

Check [this post](http://web.archive.org/web/20170521141754/http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1927582) for additional useful hotkeys

Comment: Wow. 10 years on and off playing this game, and I'm just learning this now.

Comment: @Paystey be sure to upvote the question too if it's good, Q's need love too ;P